# Link tag not working in Blazor page, how do I implement asp call in blazor?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor

for a .NET project I have to transfer my mvc application to Blazor pages.
This was going well until I had to use an ASP-controller call in my Blazor page...
The tag was initially working in my mvc project, but it became unclickable in my Blazor page.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is the code in mvc (cshtml), here is the link clickable in the browser

```
    @foreach (Sneaker sneaker in @Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="45%">@sneaker.Description</td>
            @if (@sneaker.Price != null)
            {
                <td width="15%"> € @sneaker.Price</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td width="15%">Free</td>
            }
                
            <td width="20%">@sneaker.Sex</td>
            <td width="15%">@sneaker.Id</td>
            <td width="25%">
                <a asp-controller="Sneaker" asp-area="" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@sneaker.Id">
                    Details
                </a> 
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    }
```

This is the code in my Blazor page, this link is unclickable in the browser...

```
@foreach (Sneaker sneaker in _sneakers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td width="45%">@sneaker.Description</td>
                @if (@sneaker.Price != null)
                {
                    <td width="15%"> € @sneaker.Price</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td width="15%">Free</td>
                }
                <td width="20%">@sneaker.Sex</td>
                <td width="15%">@sneaker.Id</td>
                <td width="25%">
                    <a asp-controller="Sneaker" asp-area="" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@sneaker.Id"> Details </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: I think that these helpers only work in a .cshtml page. I'm a blazor app you only have the host page like that in a server flavor, and no such pages on webassembly. So I think you should construct the URL like a regular html link, the blazor app likely does not know about the controllers at all

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `asp-controller` this way. 
In your controller just add the route like this:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class SneakerController : Controller
{
  
  public IActionResult Detail(int id)
  {
    //Your code
  }
}
```

In your blazor page: 
`<a href= $"/Sneaker/Detail/{id}">sometext</a>`